# Terraform reusing config blocks

Tags: terraform, code-duplication, datadog

Terraform noob here. I have a datadog config along the line of (shamelessly copied from terraform website):

```
resource "datadog_dashboard" "ordered_dashboard" {
  title        = "Ordered Layout Dashboard"
  description  = "Created using the Datadog provider in Terraform"
  layout_type  = "ordered"
  is_read_only = true

  widget { # SIMILAR GRAPH
    alert_graph_definition {
      alert_id  = "895605"
      viz_type  = "timeseries"
      title     = "Widget Title"
      live_span = "1h"
    }
  }

  widget { # SIMILAR GRAPH
    alert_graph_definition {
      alert_id  = "895605"
      viz_type  = "timeseries"
      title     = "Widget Title"
      live_span = "2h"
    }
  }

  widget {
    alert_value_definition {
      alert_id   = "895605"
      precision  = 3
      unit       = "b"
      text_align = "center"
      title      = "Widget Title"
    }
  }

  widget { # SIMILAR GRAPH
    alert_graph_definition {
      alert_id  = "895605"
      viz_type  = "timeseries"
      title     = "Widget Title"
      live_span = "1w"
    }
  }

  widget { # SIMILAR GRAPH
    alert_graph_definition {
      alert_id  = "895605"
      viz_type  = "timeseries"
      title     = "Widget Title"
      live_span = "2w"
    }
  }
}
```

As seen, we have 5 graphs: graph 1,2,4 and 5 are very similar, and only differ at 1 attribute, whereas graph 3 is very different. Is there a strategy in TF to reuse all the configs for graph 1,2 4 and 5?

I have attempted at using dynamic blocks, but while dynamic blocks can generate graphs 1 and 2 well, graph 3 is so different that I cannot fit it in the dynamic block.

In practice, the graphs are much more complex, and there are more of them, hence I find the config to be too hard to manage.

This is what I tried:

```
resource "datadog_dashboard" "ordered_dashboard" {
  title        = "Ordered Layout Dashboard"
  description  = "Created using the Datadog provider in Terraform"
  layout_type  = "ordered"
  is_read_only = true

  dynamic widget {
    for_each = ["1h", "2h"]
    iterator = live_span_iterator
    content {
      alert_graph_definition {
        alert_id  = "895605"
        viz_type  = "timeseries"
        title     = "Widget Title"
        live_span = live_span_iterator.value
      }
    }
  }

  widget {
    alert_value_definition {
      alert_id   = "895605"
      precision  = 3
      unit       = "b"
      text_align = "center"
      title      = "Widget Title"
    }
  }

  dynamic widget {
    for_each = ["1w", "2w"]
    iterator = live_span_iterator
    content {
      alert_graph_definition {
        alert_id  = "895605"
        viz_type  = "timeseries"
        title     = "Widget Title"
        live_span = live_span_iterator.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Are there any other strategies that might help me reduce the code duplication? I hope to retain the order of the graphs if possible.

Comment: Apart from dynamic blocks, there is nothing else withing a single resource. that you can use.  You would have to look beyond  TF, e.g pre-processing your TF files with some python script.

Comment: If you mostly do application development, you want to keep your code very DRY. Terraform code, and systems management code in general, it's OK if things are a little wet. Having a big list of similar things makes it easier to change one without impacting the others.